# How do I add an integer column to an existing table that I want to be unique but only within records with the same foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, .net-core

I have an existing table that has the following properties (among others):

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
public int Year { get; set; }
// Other properties...
```

I would like to add another property of:

```
public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
```

This column will represent a more human-readable identifier that will be shown on invoices, etc. I also want to define this column to start at `1000`, and be unique but only for the same `CustomerId`. In other words, two different customers could have an OrderNumber of `1001`.

I will probably update the table configuration to include these lines:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CustomerOrder> builder)
{
    // Existing configurations, such as 
    // builder.ToTable("CustomerOrders");

    builder.Property(p => p.OrderNumber).HasDefaultValue(1000);

    builder.HasIndex(p => new
    {
        p.CustomerId,
        p.OrderNumber
    }).IsUnique();

    // Other configurations...
}
```

I will also be handling the generation of the `OrderNumber` in the Order repository class's `Add()` method, as I'm not aware of an easy way to handle this on the database side. So my challenge is, how do I add this new column with these constraints and get all of the existing records updated to adhere to them?

I believe it needs to be done in the migration script, after adding the column and before adding the uniqueness constraint. I am not sure what kind of update script I'd need to write to make the values in that column unique after it gets added and set to `1000` on each record, but before the uniqueness constraint gets set.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Why do you want to create the same order number for different customers? You should just use an identity and be done with it.

Comment: @SeanLange It's a way to provide the customer consecutive order numbers to use for their own purposes. It's like a box of checks; if everyone had unique numbers on their checks those numbers would be massive. Perhaps a more descriptive name would be `CustomerOrderSequence`. Since internally I'll be using the unique Guid ID for business logic, can you clarify what you mean by it being a "bad idea"?

Comment: Well you could use a separate sequence for each customer. The reason I said it was a bad idea is because if you try to manage the values yourself you run into issues like concurrency and many other difficult things to deal with. But if you do something like a sequence it can work just fine.

Comment: @SeanLange Is there a way to generate separate sequences for each customer DB-side, rather than in code (using 2 db calls for a get, then an add)? That's the reason I have the `.IsUnique()` constraint on the index of `CustomerId` and `OrderNumber`, so that if any issues occur during an insert the database would throw an exception for violating the uniqueness constraint. My issue still stands of how I get existing records in that table to be updated to have the proper sequences, however. I do have optimistic concurrency handling in place for edits/deletes, but that's irrelevant here I think.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about EF but I would make your inserts in a stored procedure. Then you have proper separation between the application and data layers. Inside your procedure you would get the next value from the customer specific sequence and insert your data. The nasty part here having so many sequences and need to get the next value from the correct one.

Comment: @SeanLange I found a fairly simple solution, any thoughts?

Comment: My only comment would be that putting sql in the application is not something I condone. But glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish my goals by splitting the update into two separate migrations.

First I added the `CustomerOrderSequence` property, then altered the EF-generated migration script to do the requisite updating:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
        name: "CustomerOrderSequence",
        table: "CustomerOrders",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: 0);

    // Manual update step of the existing Customer Orders to adhere to the sequence rules.
    migrationBuilder.Sql(
        "UPDATE CustomerOrders " +
        "SET CustomerOrderSequence = OrderSequence " +
            "FROM " +
            "(" +
                "SELECT " +
                    "CustomerOrderSequence, 999 + ROW_NUMBER() " +
                "OVER " +
                "(" +
                    "PARTITION BY CustomerId " +
                    "ORDER BY CreatedUtc DESC" +
                ") AS OrderSequence " +
                "FROM CustomerOrders" +
            ") AS CustomerOrders " +
        "WHERE CustomerOrders.CustomerOrderSequence <> CustomerOrders.OrderSequence");
}
```

Then added the following update to the table's configuration:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CustomerOrder> builder)
{
    // Pre-existing configurations...

    builder.HasIndex(p => new
    {
        p.CustomerId,
        p.CustomerOrderSequence
    }).IsUnique();

    // Additional pre-existing configurations...
}
```

EF generated the appropriate migration script so that now the DB will complain if a new record is inserted that violates that uniqueness constraints. For my purposes, it is *very* unlikely that a simultaneous insert will be made here, so I just do this in my repository class for now:

```
public void AddOrder(CustomerOrder Order)
{
    int maxSequence = _context.CustomerOrders.Where(f => f.CustomerId == Order.CustomerId).Max(f => f.CustomerOrderSequence);
    Order.SetSequence(maxSequence);

    _context.CustomerOrders.Add(Order);
}
```

Where the `.SetSequence()` method sets the value to `Math.Max(1000, maxSequence + 1)` so that the `CustomerOrderSequence` property can be configured with a public getter but private setter.

If concurrency becomes an issue I'll either write raw SQL for the insert or pass the values to a stored procedure, but I doubt that will become necessary.